# Get index of enum from string?

Tags: java, android, enums

I have a string value, I also have an array of strings and an enum containing the range also.
To get the index of the string in the array, from the value supplied I write this:

```
Arrays.asList(myClass.BAUD_RATES).indexOf(username)
```

How do I do this for an enum? Can I use ordinal? Or do i have to make my own method?

The method might go like:

```
public enum Fruit {
   ...
   static public boolean isMember(String aName) {
       Fruit[] aFruits = Fruit.values();
       for (Fruit aFruit : aFruits)
           if (aFruit.fruitname.equals(aName))
               return aFruit;
       return false;
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but based on question title you may be looking for

```
YourEnum.valueOf("VALUE").ordinal(); 
//like Directions.valueOf("NORTH").ordinal();
```

1. `YourEnum.valueOf("VALUE")` returns enum *value* with name `"VALUE"`
2. each enum *value* knows its position (indexed from zero) which we can get by calling `ordinal()` method on it.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, these all work, apparently that was not my problem. The problem was that if I search the library, for say 9600 in the string array, it works fine. But when I was searching for the same value in the enum it said it was not a value in the enum. 03-15 16:04:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(19719): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 19200 is not a constant in slickdevlabs.apps.usb2seriallib.SlickUSB2Serial$BaudRate, so i will just use the string array... No idea why this is the case. Luckily the library gave a string array also.

Answer (score 15):

I might not understand you question, but the same code works for enums too:

```
int index = Arrays.asList(YourEnum.values()).indexOf(YourEnum.ENUM_ITEM);
```

Or you can get:

```
int index = YourEnum.valueOf("ENUM_ITEM").ordinal();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this simple solution:

```
Fruit.values()[index]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the index, you can use ordinal. If you want to assign some specific value to String, you may define your own method to retrieve it.

```
 enum DAY
 {
  MONDAY(10),
  TUESDAY(20);
  int value;
  DAY(int x)
  {
   this.value = x;
  }
  public int getValue()
  {
    return value;
   }
```

Now value and ordinal can be retrieved as :

```
    for(DAY s : DAY.values() )
    {
        System.out.println(s.ordinal());
        System.out.println(s.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple

```
TestEnum test = TestEnum.c;
log(test.index.toString());

enum TestEnum{
  c,d
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following logic will also work.

If you want to  check and you know the fruitname already don't use for loop go with the approach mentioned by Pshemo

```
for (Fruit aFruit : aFruits)
           if (aFruit.name().equals(aName))
               return aFruit.ordinal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding here the solution that worked for me:

```
YourEnum.values.indexOf("VALUE");
```