# Given an array of Strings, how to find out the index of a particular String?

Tags: java

I have,

```
String[] directions = {"North", "South", "West", "East"};
```

Not, I have a String s which is any one of those 4 String literals.

How do I get the index of s in directions?

Comment: You want the index. Try to search the `String` API for methods that might have a close name :).

Comment: As a side rec, in this situation I'd use an enum, not Strings since this would restrict `s` to one of the for choices and nothing else. Also enums have a  method for just this problem, `ordinal()`, although the API states that you would not likely need to use it.

Comment: If the array is sorted you can use Arrays.binarySearch

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Can you show how it can be done using enums please?

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you need the index?

Answer (score 1):

A possible enum

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH("North"), SOUTH("South"), EAST("East"), WEST("West");

    private String text;
    private Direction(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

```
public class TestDirection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%10s: %-4s%n", "Direction", "Ordinal");
        for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            System.out.printf("%10s: %-4d%n", dir.getText(), dir.ordinal());
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints out:

```
 Direction: Ordinal
     North: 0   
     South: 1   
      East: 2   
      West: 3
```

but again, the devil is in the details. As the enum API for this method states:

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a for loop as well..

```
int i, index;
for i = 0; i < directions.lenght()-1; i++{
    if(s.equals(directions[i]){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple snippet:

```
String[] directions = {"North", "South", "West", "East"};

int directionIndex = Arrays.asList(directions).indexOf("West");
```

This will give you the index of any string within the array or returns `-1` if it is absent.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use

`java.util.Arrays.asList(directions).indexOf(s)`

A more general question with several excellent answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof). The above solution is one of the answers listed there.

Comment: Thanks, buddy. How can I do the same using enums?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15436799/2429404